# Is there a way to make a bubble chart in R where the bubbles touch and one axis represents values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a bubble chart where the x-axis and size of the bubbles represent values, but the y-axis is irrelevant.  I would also like the bubbles to not overlap but be positioned next to each other.  Essentially, I'm trying to replicate this chart (just the bubbles, not the pie charts):

https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/06/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html

Is there a way to do this in R, preferably using ggplot2?  geom_jitter doesn't quite do the trick because I can't get the bubbles to reliably touch.  ggrepel doesn't currently have a solution for points: https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/20

Are there any other ideas?

Edit:
Here is an example data set and one attempt that I've made.  This attempt uses geom_jitter, but obviously the bubbles are not positioned against each other as they are in the NY Times example above.

```
library(ggplot2)
seed(1)

bubble_data = data.frame(
  variable = paste0("bubble_", 1:10),
  x_value=runif(10),
  size=runif(10)
)

bubble_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_value, y = 1, size = size)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 1), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = variable), position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[chart_attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQdu.png)

Comment: Hi Drew. Any successful solution to this question would presumably need to show a working example, and this would require a data set to use. Would you be able to provide a sample of data you would like this to work with?

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for the tip.  I've added a sample data set and one attempt I've made at solving this.